# Link from Wordpress site to Buddypress Profile

Tags: buddypress

I try to link from the Wordpress Page Editor to the Buddypress Profile.
I installed 'Insert PHP v1.2' to use php, but i still dont get it. Actually I do the following steps in my Wordpress page:

[kleo_h3]Füge weitere [kleo_colored_text color="#F00056"]Fotos [/kleo_colored_text]zu deinem Profil hinzu.[/kleo_h3]

[rtmedia_uploader]

[insert_php]

&var = bp_loggedin_user_domain();

echo do_shortcode('[kleo_button url=&var style="standard" size="small" round="round" icon="{fontawesome-icon,after" target="_self"] Profil [/kleo_button]');

[/insert_php]

But the programm crahes. How I get that URL into the shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally:

[kleo_h3]Füge weitere [kleo_colored_text color="#F00056"]Fotos [/kleo_colored_text]zu deinem Profil hinzu.[/kleo_h3]

[rtmedia_uploader]

[insert_php]

//$var =bp_core_get_userlink( bp_loggedin_user_id());

$id= bp_loggedin_user_id();

$name = bp_core_get_user_displayname($id);

$url = site_url()."/members/$name";

echo do_shortcode('[kleo_button url='.$url.' style="standard" size="small" round="round" icon="{fontawesome-icon,after" target="_self"] Profil [/kleo_button]');

[/insert_php]